# MySQL- Query to Get Stats on Unique Rosters (League of Legends Champion Rosters)

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a table called "kda_stats" where I keep stats of player performances per match. It looks like this

| match | team | player | champion | winning_team |

| 150            | 5            | 20             | gragas        | 5            |

| 150            | 5            | 21             | kalista      | 5            |

| 150            | 5            | 22             | elise          | 5            |

| 150            | 5            | 23             | nasus      | 5            |

| 150            | 5            | 24             | thresh      | 5            |

| 150            | 6            | 30             | yasuo      | 5            |

| 150            | 6            | 31             | nasus      | 5            |

| 150            | 6            | 32             | braum      | 5            |

| 150            | 6            | 33             | jinx          | 5            |

| 150            | 6            | 34             | jax           | 5            |

I want to run a query where I can get unique sets of team rosters - so a set of the 5 champions picked by a team in a match, and then get stats for how that set of 5 performed.

How can I write a query to do this?

An example stat of what I'm trying to achieve would be like this:

| Unique Champion Roster                 | Games | Win% |

| gragas, kalista, elise, nasus, thresh | 12         | 30%

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the StackOverflow's help first. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: ...and format code without the "&nbsp"s

Comment: (And that team would appear to have a 100% track record)